# What are the little questions/comments that I see attached to some questions and answers?

Tags: support

[image]

It seems to be a basic StackExchange feature that I just can't understand.  I feel I am being bone-headed in some way.  I have looked through the help, and tried clicking everyting I can find in the browser.

I don't know what they are called, and I wonder how they are made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is more hidden than it should be. You aren't being bone-headed.

They're called comments. Once you earn [50 reputation points](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) you gain the ability to write them.

You can't find the link to do it yet because you haven't accumulated sufficient reputation points on this site, but once you do, you'll find them much less confusing!

Comment: Thank you @Daniel.  I don't feel so bone-headed now.

Comment: @505 As you can see here, when you ask a question, you can comment so when you ask a good question like this on e main site, you can comment there and also will likely get some votes and reputation from up votes.

Comment: You can always comment on your own question or answers, no matter your reputation. The limit only prevents you from commenting on other questions/answers.